# Sticky socket.io sessions by cookie for node.js cluster without sticky express sessions

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, load-balancing

I am working with the `express` and `socket.io` libraries of Node.js on the **same server**, listening on the **same port**. I would like to use the `cluster` module to support round-robin load balancing, but I want the load-balancing behavior for `express` and `socket.io` to be different. The behavior is as follows:

1. Incoming connections for HTTP/S should connect to any single worker
2. Incoming connections for WS/S should connect to a specific worker, based on a **cookie value**---more broadly, based on a value

Are there any available libraries to accomplish my desired behaviors? If not, how should I go about accomplishing these behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of ways you could do this. I'm gonna link you to [this guide on using redis as a pub sub](https://github.com/rajaraodv/redispubsub) but also I'll give you a super short overview of what it could look like.

So spawn two clusters at start up, or however many you want..

```
var aWorker = cluster.fork();
var bWorker = cluster.fork();
```

then you need to set them up to listen on their respective ports, so using the net module:

```
var server1 = require('net').createServer([options], function( connection ) {
    aWorker.send( 'ConnectionEvent' , connection );
}).listen(80); //HTTP/WS
var server2 = require('net').createServer([options], function( connection ) {
    bWorker.send( 'ConnectionEvent' , connection );
}).listen(443); //HTTPS/WSS
```

In your cluster process:

```
var app_server = require('express')().listen( 0, 'localhost' );
var io = require('socket.io')(app_server);
io.adapter(require('socket.io-redis')({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: **REDIS PORT** });
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //Rest of your io server code
...

process.on( 'message' , function( message, connection ) {
    if( connection && message === 'ConnectionEvent' ) {
        app_server.emit( 'connection', connection );
        connection.resume();
    }
}
```

I believe the room function of Socket.io would accomplish what you're trying to do in your second point rather than relying on creating new worker tasks. That's just my opinion though.